# How can I set this bootstrap footer position fixed at bottom it is coming after my carousel container in iPad view?

Tags: css, media-queries, css-position, footer

This is media query I am using for changing position of footer to fixed but this media query is not working.

```
@media only screen and(max-width: 800px) {
    footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

This is my footer I am using bootstrap footer.

```
<footer class="text-muted text-center text-small bg-dark container-fluid navbar navbar-default navbar-static-bottom justify-content-center">
    <p>© 2017–2021 iCoder</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hellooo,

You can use "fixed-bottom" class in bootstrap to do that.

```
<footer
  class="
    text-muted text-center text-small
    bg-dark
    container-fluid
    navbar navbar-default navbar-static-bottom
    justify-content-center
    fixed-bottom
  "
>
  <p>© 2017–2021 iCoder</p>
</footer>
```

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: hi,

Thanks for reply. I have already tried this this makes footer fixed and I want that footer should be at the bottom of page. It works fine when I decrease size of browser . But when I switch to ipad view in tools footer is shown beneath the content of website and a lot of space is left beneath it. So thats why I used this media query to set it to fixed when it reaches ipad width. But media query is not working . Could you please check media query syntax?.

Comment: can you try removing your css file. It will work then I think.